# Sending email in Java not working when switching computers?

Tags: java, api, port, jakarta-mail

I found the base of this code in another stackoverflow thread (will be sure to cite for my project but left the url at school) and got the code to work perfectly on the schools computer (using the 587 port) however when I try the same code at home on the same software (JCreator) the program doesn't work anymore and gives this error:

```
<pre> <code> 
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at SendEmail.<init>(SendEmail.java:86)
    at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:93)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at SendEmail.<init>(SendEmail.java:78)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:486)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1902)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 24 more

Process completed.
</code>  </pre>
```

If it's any easier, this is the code. The code originally came in one huge main method but I tried to change it so that there is a method (didnt work) so I made one huge constructor ... is that okay? Also, it uses the Java API

```
<pre> <code> 

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
SendEmail Class
By: Jana Dbouk
June 06, 2014
ICS 4U0 - Mr. Campos

SendEmail Class Functions:
        * Volunteer student enters custom email message
        * Program sends email to Mr. Makridis
        * Self Testing Main Method

 */

public class SendEmail
{

    public SendEmail ()
    {

final String username = "jaebear.x0@gmail.com";
 final String password = "sugarcakes"; 
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";


        // Connects to the email host
        Properties emailProperties = new Properties ();
         emailProperties .put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
         emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
         emailProperties .put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


        // Checks to see if student volunteer's email/password are correct
       Session session = Session.getInstance (emailProperties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator ()
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication ()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication (username, password);
            }
        }
        );

        // Send a email to the teacher

        try
        {

            Message emailToTeacher = new MimeMessage (session);

            // Volunteer student's email
            emailToTeacher.setFrom (new InternetAddress ("jaebear.x0@gmail.comm"));

            // Teacher's email
            emailToTeacher.setRecipients (Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse ("acentius@outlook.com"));

            // Subject Title
            emailToTeacher.setSubject ("New Email from Breakfast Club");

            // Text within email
            String emailMessage = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the email message.");
            emailToTeacher.setText (emailMessage);

            // Sends emailToTeacher to teacher
            Transport.send (emailToTeacher);

            // Let's the student know the emailToTeacher has been sent
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Email successfully sent to Mr. Makridis.");

        }
        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException (e); // Error message

        }

    }     // Self testing main method
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new SendEmail ();
    }
} </code>  </pre>
```

Comment: Which line in your program does the trace say started the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a certificate error, not a code error.

I wrote a blog post about it a couple years back:

http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/29/fixing-pkix-path-building-issues-when-using-javamail-and-smtp/